# YOCTO - Build partial image for application

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I want to create a small application image. That image installed at a separate partition shall be mounted to /usr/local. I created a recipe like this:

```
inherit image
IMAGE_BASENAME = "appfs"
IMAGE_NAME_SUFFIX = ".appfs"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " app_lib "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " app_prog1 "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " app_prog2 "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " app_prog3 "
```

The result looks not bad, I can control the installation of the files by the prefix-Variable in the recipes of the application programms. So the will be installed in /bin, which means /usr/local/bin in the device.

But the image contains the whole directory structure of a root filesystem. Is there any comfortable way to generate the reduced directory structure of the /usr/local directory? Or do I need to clean it up by myself in a IMAGE_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a package or package group and not an image.

An image is a full distribution installation, usually using the poky distro.
This is built-in to yocto and unavoidable, as all dependencies of your app will need to be in the image. (runtimes, supporting libs, basic linux env, etc.)

In your `tmp/deploy/rpm` or `tmp/deploy/deb` directory you should have packages related to your apps.

Something that may help organize is to create a [package group](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-customimage-customtasks) to aggregate your applications.

Comment: Sorry, but can I generate a separate image (e.g. ext4) from a packagegroup?

The reason: We need 100% reliability, also during an update. The operating system (OS) will change rarely and is big, the application (APP) will change more often and is small.

We split the flash in five partitions, two for OS, two for APP and a variable space. One of these both is active and read-only, the update shall be copied to the inactive one. After that we just switch the active partitions and reboot. If power supply fails at any moment, the device will work with the last or new version - always.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your `tmp/deploy/images/<machine>/<imagename>.manifest` file you will notice that in addition to the packages you specified, some additional ones such as `libc6` and `base-files` are included.

You can remove them by naming the packages in `ROOTFS_RO_UNNEEDED`. This variable is used to remove recipes such as `shadow` and `run-postinsts` which are processed when creating a read-only image. You can add the other undesirable recipes to this list until your manifest matches exactly the packages you want included.

For example:

```
# tested with Yocto 2.6
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "ext4"
IMAGE_INSTALL = "my-go-app" 
inherit image

# Don't run ldconfig on the rootfs
LDCONFIGDEPEND = ""

# If not building an RO filesystem, you can force use of ROOTFS_RO_UNNEEDED
# but be aware of the other packages included in the variable by image.bbclass 
FORCE_RO_REMOVE = "1"

# Use _append because image.bbclass includes other packages
ROOTFS_RO_UNNEEDED_append = "base-files base-files-lic \
                            bash bash-lic \
                            libc6 libc6-lic \
                            ncurses-libtinfo libtinfo5 \
                            opkg-utils-lic \
                            ncurses-terminfo-base ncurses-lic \
                            run-postinsts-lic \
                            "
```

The resulting filesystem I get looks like this:

```
tmp
├── etc
│   ├── shells.rpmsave
│   ├── timestamp
│   └── version
├── lost+found [error opening dir]
├── usr
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── my-go-app
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── go
│   │       └── pkg
│   │           └── linux_arm64_dynlink
│   │               └── libstd.so
│   └── share
│       ├── common-licenses
│       │   └── license.manifest
│       └── licenses
│           ├── go-runtime
│           │   ├── generic_BSD-3-Clause
│           │   └── LICENSE
│           └── my-go-app
└── var
    ├── cache
    └── lib
```

There may still be a few files left to clean up using a postprocess function:

```
postprocess_partial_image() {
  rm -f ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/shells.rpmsave
  rm -rf ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/var 
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "postprocess_partial_image; "
```